# Angularjs load view in background

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

When a user first comes to my app they come to my homepage which is just some static text. I have a second page called "My News" which has content that is specific for that user which comes from my database. If the user navigates to "My News" it takes a around 5 seconds to load (ajax request, etc). I would like to as soon as the app loads to automatically start preloading the "My News" view (localstorage from previous sessions contains the userid and other information I need to get the custom data). This way when they click "My News" there is no longer such a long delay and it look almost instant. I have looked at $templateCache but it does not look like a solution if you need to make ajax calls. Is there a standard or best practice solution for such a scenario?

Comment: You can create an init method in your controller, and send an ajax call to get the content of the page, on response you can simply put it into $templateCache ?

Comment: With an init method if the user clicks "My news" before the init function has completed (e.g still waiting for db to respond) will it rerun everything from scratch again?